# chef server reconfigure error - User name may not contain "<" or start with "["

Tags: ruby, postgresql, chef-infra

I am trying to install Chef server 12.15 onto RHEL7.3 as a standalone server with no connection to the internet.

After installing via rpm, I added the following line to `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb`:

```
# cat /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb 
bootstrap['enable']=false
oc_chef_pedant['debug_org_creation']=true
```

When running `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` after a fresh install of Chef Server.

Then, I run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure`, and the following output occurred.
From my understanding, the main error seems to be `User name may not contain "<" or start with "["`, but I cannot tell why a user would be inserted that includes one of those characters.

```
# chef-server-ctl reconfigure
... (apparently successful up through 'Recipe: private-chef::erchef_database'
Recipe: private-chef::bifrost_database
  * private_chef_pg_user[bifrost] action create
    - Create PostgreSQL user bifrost
    -   Set password
  * private_chef_pg_user[bifrost_ro] action create
    - Create PostgreSQL user bifrost_ro
    -   Set password
  * private_chef_pg_database[bifrost] action create
    - Create database bifrost
  * private_chef_pg_sqitch[/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db] action deploy
    - Deploying schema from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db
    * execute[sqitch_deploy_/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db] action run

      ================================================================================
      Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[sqitch_deploy_/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db]'
      ================================================================================

      Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
      ------------------------------------
      Expected process to exit with [0, 1], but received '2'
      ---- Begin output of sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db deploy --verify ----
      STDOUT: Adding metadata tables to bifrost
      STDERR: User name may not contain "<" or start with "["
      ---- End output of sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db deploy --verify ----
      Ran sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db deploy --verify returned 2

      Resource Declaration:
      ---------------------
      # In /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/providers/pg_sqitch.rb

       11:     execute "sqitch_deploy_#{new_resource.name}" do
       12:       command <<-EOM.gsub(/\s+/," ").strip!
       13:         sqitch --engine pg
       14:                --db-name #{new_resource.database}
       15:                --db-host #{new_resource.hostname}
       16:                --db-port #{new_resource.port}
       17:                --db-user #{new_resource.username}
       18:                --top-dir #{new_resource.name}
       19:                deploy #{target} --verify
       20:       EOM
       21:       environment "PERL5LIB" => "", # force us to use omnibus perl
       22:                   "PGPASSWORD" => new_resource.password
       23:
       24:       # Sqitch Return Codes
       25:       # 0 - when changes are applied
       26:       # 1 - when everything is ok but no changes were made
       27:       # 2(+?) - when an error occurs.
       28:       returns [0,1]
       29:     end
       30:   end

      Compiled Resource:
      ------------------
      # Declared in /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/providers/pg_sqitch.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in class_from_file'

      execute("sqitch_deploy_/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db") do
        action [:run]
        retries 0
        retry_delay 2
        default_guard_interpreter :execute
        command "sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db deploy --verify"
        backup 5
        environment {"PERL5LIB"=>"", "PGPASSWORD"=>"50c444fb5d49a81e73e8412e4cc5b33ffe51e249ebd509731cbec7d44e3e7a5a03b8b054eeddce00e6fe352c02b9ce41d39d"}
        returns [0, 1]
        user nil
        declared_type :execute
        cookbook_name "private-chef"
      end

      Platform:
      ---------
      x86_64-linux


    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `deploy` on resource 'private_chef_pg_sqitch[/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    execute[sqitch_deploy_/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db] (/var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/providers/pg_sqitch.rb line 11) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0, 1], but received '2'
    ---- Begin output of sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db deploy --verify ----
    STDOUT: Adding metadata tables to bifrost
    STDERR: User name may not contain "<" or start with "["
    ---- End output of sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db deploy --verify ----
    Ran sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db deploy --verify returned 2

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/recipes/bifrost_database.rb

     42: private_chef_pg_sqitch "/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db" do
     43:   hostname postgres_attrs['vip']
     44:   port     postgres_attrs['port']
     45:   username  postgres_attrs['db_superuser']
     46:   password PrivateChef.credentials.get('postgresql', 'db_superuser_password')
     47:   database "bifrost"
     48:   action :nothing
     49: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/recipes/bifrost_database.rb:42:in `from_file'

    private_chef_pg_sqitch("/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db") do
      action [:nothing]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :private_chef_pg_sqitch
      cookbook_name "private-chef"
      recipe_name "bifrost_database"
      hostname "127.0.0.1"
      port 5432
      username "opscode-pgsql"
      password "50c444fb5d49a81e73e8412e4cc5b33ffe51e249ebd509731cbec7d44e3e7a5a03b8b054eeddce00e6fe352c02b9ce41d39d"
      database "bifrost"
    end

    Platform:
    ---------
    x86_64-linux


Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 17 resources updated in 33 seconds
[2017-07-07T11:34:23+09:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-07-07T11:34:23+09:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-07-07T11:34:23+09:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: private_chef_pg_sqitch[/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db] (private-chef::bifrost_database line 42) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[sqitch_deploy_/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db] (/var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/providers/pg_sqitch.rb line 11) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0, 1], but received '2'
---- Begin output of sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db deploy --verify ----
STDOUT: Adding metadata tables to bifrost
STDERR: User name may not contain "<" or start with "["
---- End output of sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db deploy --verify ----
Ran sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/db deploy --verify returned 2
```

Does anyone know what is the cause of the above error and how can I fix it?

Any details would be appreciated, such as what user should be getting created. I don't know Ruby language, so looking at the source code hasn't been so fruitful unfortunately.

As a little more information, possibly useful and related, this problem came up before in version version 12.14 when I was trying to install it, and after running `reconfigure` 3 times, finally it worked apparently without any changes to the configuration, but I was then unable to add an admin user due to mysterious http 500 / database error. (For more details about that probably related issue, see my post on the [Chef forum](https://discourse.chef.io/t/unable-to-create-first-user-due-to-error-500/11135)).

Not having heard a response to the above post, I tried uninstalling 12.14 and starting from scratch with 12.15, only to find the same issues being reproduced.

Help appreciated.

**Update**

As expected from the same issue with version 12.14, after running `chef-server-cfg reconfigure` for the THIRD time, the command finished successfully, with the following output:

```
Deprecated features used!
  An attempt was made to change sysvinit_id from "SV" to nil by calling sysvinit_id(nil). In Chef 12, this does a get rather
    - /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/enterprise/recipes/runit.rb:31:in `block in from_file'
   See https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_custom_resource_cleanups.html for further details.
  Cloning resource attributes for runit_service[redis_lb] from prior resource
Previous runit_service[redis_lb]: /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/enterprise/definitions/component_runit_service.
Current  runit_service[redis_lb]: /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/recipes/redis_lb.rb:83:in `from_fi
    - /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/recipes/redis_lb.rb:83:in `from_file'
   See https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_resource_cloning.html for further details.
  Cloning resource attributes for directory[/var/opt/opscode/nginx/etc/addon.d] from prior resource
Previous directory[/var/opt/opscode/nginx/etc/addon.d]: /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/recipes/oc_i
Current  directory[/var/opt/opscode/nginx/etc/addon.d]: /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/recipes/ngin
    - /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/recipes/nginx.rb:35:in `block in from_file'
   See https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_resource_cloning.html for further details.
  Chef::Platform.find_provider_for_node is deprecated at 1 location:
    - /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/forwardable.rb:188:in `execute_each_resource'
   See https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_chef_platform_methods.html for further details.
  Chef::Platform.find_provider is deprecated at 1 location:
    - /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/forwardable.rb:188:in `execute_each_resource'
   See https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_chef_platform_methods.html for further details.
  Chef::Platform.find is deprecated at 1 location:
   See https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_chef_platform_methods.html for further details.

Chef Client finished, 385/973 resources updated in 02 minutes 21 seconds
Chef Server Reconfigured!
```

After this apparently successful reconfiguring, attempts to add an admin user fail with internal server error 500:

```
# chef-server-ctl user-create admin admin admin 'username@example.com' 'password'
ERROR: Server returned error 500 for https://127.0.0.1/users/, retrying 1/5 in 4s
ERROR: Server returned error 500 for https://127.0.0.1/users/, retrying 2/5 in 5s
ERROR: Server returned error 500 for https://127.0.0.1/users/, retrying 3/5 in 11s
ERROR: Server returned error 500 for https://127.0.0.1/users/, retrying 4/5 in 30s
ERROR: Server returned error 500 for https://127.0.0.1/users/, retrying 5/5 in 61s
ERROR: internal server error
Response: internal service error
```

The logs from time's postgresql show as follows, with no other messages from that time.

```
# chef-server-ctl tail postgresql
2017-07-07_08:15:31.54798              AND name = $2
2017-07-07_08:15:31.54799              AND expires_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at time zone 'utc'
2017-07-07_08:15:31.54799            ORDER BY type DESC
2017-07-07_08:16:32.56806 ERROR:  relation "keys_by_name" does not exist at character 87
2017-07-07_08:16:32.56810 STATEMENT:  SELECT id, org_id, name, authz_id, type, key_name, public_key, key_version
2017-07-07_08:16:32.56811             FROM keys_by_name
2017-07-07_08:16:32.56811            WHERE (org_id = $1 OR org_id = 'global')
2017-07-07_08:16:32.56811              AND name = $2
2017-07-07_08:16:32.56812              AND expires_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at time zone 'utc'
2017-07-07_08:16:32.56812            ORDER BY type DESC

# grep -r '07_08:16' /var/log/opscode
/var/log/opscode/postgresql/9.2/current:2017-07-07_08:16:32.56806 ERROR:  relation "keys_by_name" does not exist at character 87
/var/log/opscode/postgresql/9.2/current:2017-07-07_08:16:32.56810 STATEMENT:  SELECT id, org_id, name, authz_id, type, key_name, public_key, key_version
/var/log/opscode/postgresql/9.2/current:2017-07-07_08:16:32.56811             FROM keys_by_name
/var/log/opscode/postgresql/9.2/current:2017-07-07_08:16:32.56811            WHERE (org_id = $1 OR org_id = 'global')
/var/log/opscode/postgresql/9.2/current:2017-07-07_08:16:32.56811              AND name = $2
/var/log/opscode/postgresql/9.2/current:2017-07-07_08:16:32.56812              AND expires_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at time zone 'utc'
/var/log/opscode/postgresql/9.2/current:2017-07-07_08:16:32.56812            ORDER BY type DESC
/var/log/opscode/opscode-erchef/current:2017-07-07_08:16:32.57107 [error] {<<"method=POST; path=/users/; status=500; ">>,"Internal Server Error"}
```

So, from this, it appears as though the database is still not fully built per application's expectations. Not entirely clear if this error is related to the previous error however, such as whether it may be a symptom.

Why is the database schema / insertion queries failing? How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the GECOS field for the user FROM which I had switched to become the root user had a '<' in it, as below:

```
# getent passwd origuser
origuser:x:111:111:My Name <username@example.com>:/home/origuser:/bin/bash
```

That username (probably because it is the user from which `sudo su -` was executed), was used for the default user name by [`sqitch`](http://sqitch.org/), the database change tool / Perl module used for managing Chef's database.  Adding in a stack trace to the part of Sqitch.pm that was throwing the `User name may not contain "<" or start with "["` error shows this much:

```
# /opt/opscode/embedded/bin/sqitch --engine pg --db-name bifrost --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-port 5432 --db-user opscode-pgsql --top-dir /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_
Trace begun at /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/App/Sqitch.pm line 32
App::Sqitch::__ANON__('My Name <username@example.com>') called at /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/App/Sqitch/Role/DBIEngine.pm line 321
App::Sqitch::Role::DBIEngine::register_project('App::Sqitch::Engine::pg=HASH(0xd204e0)') called at /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/App/Sqitch/Engine.pm line 130
App::Sqitch::Engine::deploy('App::Sqitch::Engine::pg=HASH(0xd204e0)', undef, 'all', 0) called at /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/App/Sqitch/Command/deploy.pm line 90
App::Sqitch::Command::deploy::execute('App::Sqitch::Command::deploy=HASH(0x3a02f00)') called at /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/App/Sqitch.pm line 311
App::Sqitch::try {...}  at /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/Try/Tiny.pm line 98
eval {...} at /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/Try/Tiny.pm line 94
Try::Tiny::try('CODE(0x39a37e8)', 'Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x2aa19c0)') called at /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/App/Sqitch.pm line 325
App::Sqitch::go('App::Sqitch') called at /opt/opscode/embedded/bin/sqitch line 16
User name may not contain "<" or start with "["
```

(Such a choice for a username seems poorly documented to say the least, but the maker of `sqitch` admits that it is a work in progress).

Anyway, after removing the special characters from the username, uninstalling Chef server, including deleting all directories previously made, and reinstalling the full Chef server, the command to add a user is successful:

```
# chef-server-ctl user-create admin admin admin 'username@example.com' 'password'
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So, the server install and user looks successful and it is onto the next steps.

It's not entirely clear how/whether/why exactly the above username-related failure would cause the other deployment issues, but at least the above steps will fix the issue, and seem generally in line with the Chef forum's common discussion to reinstall and/or run `reconfigure`.